# Issue with add google custom search code on Shopify store

Tags: shopify, google-custom-search

Hello I'm new to stackoverflow, I've recently added google custom search to my store for customers to use to look about information and learn more about the type of products I'm selling. When I added the GCS code to a new template on Shopify I made I had a few issues. The main issues have been solved by editing the search engine itself, in the "look and feel" menu, but one small issue remained. On the search bar for the search engine, there seems to be these dark thin divider lines which I can't seem to get rid of. I have very little coding experience so I'm not sure exactly what is wrong in the code itself. So i'm reaching out here to hopefully find a solution.

(Here is the code below)

```html
<div class="grid">

  <div class="grid__item post-large--two-thirds push--post-large--one-sixth">

    <div class="section-header">
      <h1 class="section-header--title">{{ page.title }}</h1>
    </div>

   <div class="rte">
      {{ page.content }}
    
    </div>
  <body>
  
  <script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '011286737035659106182:hqm_unmmoqy';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);})();
</script>
<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
    
  </body>
 
  
</div>
```

Comment: I hope the edits I've made help, I was having an issue with adding the code as plain text.

Comment: I also just ran the code and the thin divider lines are not appearing which is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There is some properties in your theme css and in the plugin css that make appear those borders.
I made two CSS snippets to remove all the borders or to keep a single border. Chose which one that you prefer :)

Add this in your css file, or between balise `<style></style>`

With single border :

```
<style>
form.gsc-search-box{
  border : none;
}
form.gsc-search-box .gsc-input-box table{
   margin-bottom : unset;
}
form.gsc-search-box .gsc-input-box table .gsib_b{
   display : none;
}
form.gsc-search-box table.gsc-search-box{
   margin : 0;
}
form.gsc-search-box table.gsc-search-box td{
    border : none;
}
```

OR

Without any border :

```
.gsc-control-searchbox-only form.gsc-search-box{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

form.gsc-search-box .gsc-input-box table{
      margin-bottom : unset;
   }
   form.gsc-search-box .gsc-input-box table .gsib_b{
      display : none;
   }

form.gsc-search-box table.gsc-search-box{
    margin : 0;
}
form.gsc-search-box table.gsc-search-box td{
    border : none;
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean exactly, could you point out the margin-bottom on the search div and the useless cell in my table?

Comment: I recently added the code you suggested and the search bar look alot batter but there are still "divider lines" but not as much and they're more orgainized I guess you can say. If i had to guess, given very little expirence with coding, this is because the points you've made above, the margin bottm and the useless cell or maybe where I placed the code you suggested.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? Maybe your theme css files impact the search bar. 
And don't worry, it's not because of the emplacement of my code.

Comment: Definitely, since the page hasn't launched yet you will most likely need the password to enter the site. The password is batter and here is a link to the page with the search engine https://n3urohub.com/pages/n3uronet

Comment: I updated the answer with the correct CSS made for your theme.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately when I added the new code it caused the search bar to disappear entirely.

Comment: I've noticed that when I add both sets of code, although I must add </style> for the botttom code, it looks like it moves the search engine up to the search bar in the top left. The word search appearing twice inside the bar.

Comment: You didn't close the style element. Revert to old version and copy the style that I sent in the custom.scss.liquid

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have much experience in this so I'm having a hard time understanding what you're directing me to do. What do you mean by the custom.scss.liquid and style element and that you sent the needed styles in the custom.scss.liquid exactly i'm not familiar with those terms although I could guess but I would prefer to ask just to be sure. If possible, could you send screenshots of what you're referring too and maybe how I may get to it, assuming you can view them on your side?

Comment: Sorry I can't view theme on my side.
Go in your Shopify back office
go to Online Store => Theme => Action => Edit code
Find in your filelist on the left side a file that finish by ".scss.liquid" or by ".css"
Add the code above

Comment: Sorry about that, for some reason the comment I intended wasn't posted. I looked through the files listed and I couldn't find any files with css at the end. I did find a few with scss.liquid at the end. They were theme.scss.liquid, timber.scss.liquid and gift-card.scss.liquid. I wasn't sure if there was a specific place to add it, since you said before that it wasn't necessary, I just added it at the bottom. I added both sets of code, one at a time, with no effect. The single broader one did mess up my theme layout.

Comment: I just checked and I can't see your code in the theme.scss.liquid. 
Can you make sure to copy/paste it at the end of the file and then save it?

Comment: Oh no I removed it when I first added both sets of code separately. I'll re-add the one that messed up my theme so you can take a look.

Comment: Are you still available?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Sorry I was AFK for sometime. The issue was addressed but unfortunately I had to close the Shopify store. Thank you again for your help!